# beautifulsoup parse breakline into one line

Tags: parsing, beautifulsoup, tags, html-parsing, line-breaks

I'm trying to extract data from tags, then save into one line as a txt file. 
For example:

```
text1, text2, text3
```

The condition is between "executives" or "Corporate Participants" until Operator.

Example of the html tags:

> ```
> <p class="p p1">
>     <strong>
>      Executives
>     </strong>
>   </p>
>   <p class="p p1">
>    text1
>   </p>
>   <p class="p p1">
>   text2
>   </p>
>   <p class="p p1">
>    text3
>   </p>
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you write lines with "`\n`", this is newline character in file. you can change your last line code to:

```
indexFile.write(parti.get_text(strip=True) + ',')
```

Then the output will be:

```
text1, text2, text3
```